# How to get the category wise values related to user?

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a Diary Management Script using PHP and MySQL. I am stuck with a situation for which I am presenting below a hypothetical table structure and my requirement.

```
 
|---------------|--------------|
|  User Name    |   Status     |
|---------------|--------------|
|  John         |   Open       |
|---------------|--------------|
|  John         |   Assigned   |
|---------------|--------------|
|  John         |   Closed     |
|---------------|--------------|
|  Miller       |   Assigned   |
|---------------|--------------|
|  Miller       |   Assigned   |
|---------------|--------------|
|  Smith        |   Closed     |
|---------------|--------------|
```

I am expecting an ultimate webpage output like the below.

```
|---------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|  User Name    |   Open       |  Assigned    | Closed       |
|---------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|  John         |      1       |       1      |     1        |
|---------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|  Miller       |      0       |       2      |     0        |
|---------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|  Smith        |      0       |       0      |     1        |
|---------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
```

Please suggest if using MySQL query(using GROUP BY) itself can produce this ready made or I have to get the help of little bit of Programming logic. If so what should I code? I am very much helpless. I could provide the entire script here, but I did not do just to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select `User Name`,
    sum(case when Status = 'Open' then 1 end) as Open,
    sum(case when Status = 'Assigned' then 1 end) as Assigned,
    sum(case when Status = 'Closed' then 1 end) as Closed
from Status
group by `User Name`
```