# Mysql query for display same column twice with respect to category

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table name user, in this table users have their names and categories (e.g : student , employee).

Now I want to display the users in other table as user separated by type like all the user that are student will display in student column and all the user that are employee will display in Employee column.

Example :

User Table:

```
Name       Category
John       Student
Jack       Student
Fred       Employee
```

Output table:

```
ID    Student    Employee
1     John     
2     Jack
3                 Fred
```

What will be the query to display that table.

Comment: What did you tried ? & show some code please this is not clear

Comment: Please have a look at the [Formatting Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and format your question to make it readable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932548/how-to-get-the-category-wise-values-related-to-user

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  ID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Student' THEN Name ELSE NULL END) Student,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Employee' THEN Name ELSE NULL END) Employee
FROM    User
GROUP   BY ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/903fa/1)

RESULT

```
╔════╦═════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║ STUDENT ║ EMPLOYEE ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ John    ║ (null)   ║
║  2 ║ Jack    ║ (null)   ║
║  3 ║ (null)  ║ Fred     ║
╚════╩═════════╩══════════╝
```

**UPDATE 1**

if you have other categories, then a *dynamic sql* is preferred,

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(case when Category = ''',
      Category,
      ''' then Name end) AS ',
      Category
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM User;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  ID, ', @sql, ' 
                    FROM    User
                    GROUP   BY ID');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/903fa/3)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with other category*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0253/1)